# const initialization of several data members

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

I would like to have a C++ class that gets initialized from a file that contains a bunch of data, reads the data, and stores it as `const` data members.

What I currently do is

```cpp
MyClass(const std::string & fileName):
datum0(),
datum1(),
datum2()
{
  this->read(fileName);
  // read() sets all datumX data members.
}
```

This has the disadvantage that the `datumX`s cannot be marked `const` anymore since they are set up after the actual initialization step.

What would be a good pattern here?

Comment: `const` data members are rarely a good idea in C++. For example, they will prevent you from putting `MyClass` objects into a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of set of datumX members - use struct with these members which have constructor from file. And make this struct const data member of your class:

```
class MyClass {
   ...
   struct MyData {
     MyData(const string& filename) { read(filename); }
     void read(const string& filename);
     int datum1;
     int datum2;
     ...
   };
   const MyData myData;
   MyClass(const string& filename) : myData(filename) {}
};
```

Comment: This doesn't help.  The `MyClass` constructor would have to call `myData.read` to set `datum1`, etc.  This means either `MyData::read` needs to be `const`, or `myData` needs to be not `const`.  Also, `filename` should probably only be a parameter of either `MyData::MyData` or `MyData::read`, but not both.

Comment: @Fraser - it is not MyClass call read() but MyData call read(). I thought it is obvious - just did update to make it clear. This was reason for (-1)?

Comment: Yes.  It wasn't obvious.  It would be if you made `read` private ;-)  -1 removed since edit.

Comment: @Fraser thanks Qs shall be obvious, I give the freedom to OP to make entire MyData private or public - these details are not present in Q.

Comment: I mean if `read` is a private function of `MyData`, there can be no confusion about `MyClass` calling it.

Answer (score 2):

Separate parsing and construction:

```
struct MyClass
{
    int const a;
    int const b;

    MyClass(int a_, int b_) : a(a_), b(b_) { }
};

MyClass readMyClass(std::istream & is)
{
    int a, b;

    // ...

    return MyClass(a, b);
}
```

Now you can say:

```
std::ifstream is("data.bin");
MyClass mc = readMyClass(is);
```

You can also make the reader function a `static` class member function and the constructor `private` if you prefer.